# TimeoutException Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

After starting the scraper something strange happens: it either works properly, ends after visiting the second page and clicking the Next button, or it somehow ends up on the property page, when I use the code with the line that is currently commented out. However, when that line is placed as it is now, it seems to work, it visits all the pages and scrapes them, and eventually, I get a time out. I am unsure what the issue is? Any tips?
The current code:

```
class PropertyFoxSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'property_fox'
    start_urls = [
        'https://propertyfox.co.za/listing-search?currentpage=1&term_id=62515&keywords=Western+Cape&orderby=createddate:desc&status%5B%5D=Active'
    ]


    def __init__(self):
        #path to driver
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('my_path')
    

    def parse(self,response):
        url = self.driver.get(response.url)
        while True:
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(lambda driver: self.driver.current_url != url) 
            try: 
                elem = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "pagerNext")))
                elem.click()
                #WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(lambda driver: self.driver.current_url != url)
                url = self.driver.current_url
                yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_page, dont_filter=False)
            except TimeoutException:
                break



    def parse_page(self, response):
        for prop in response.css('div.property-item'):
            link = prop.css('a::attr(href)').get()
            banner = prop.css('div.property-figure-icon div::text').get()
            sold_tag = None
            if banner:
                banner = banner.strip()
                sold_tag = 'sold' if 'sold' in banner.lower() else None

            yield scrapy.Request(
                link,
                callback=self.parse_property,
                meta={'item': {
                    'agency': self.name,
                    'url': link,
                    'offering': 'buy',
                    'banners': banner,
                    'sold_tag':  sold_tag,
                }},
            )

    def parse_property(self, response):
        item = response.meta.get('item')
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem that Selenium "recognize" even disabled Next button as clickable element and still tries to click it even on last page. You can try below code to make it work:

```
def parse(self,response):
    self.driver.get(response.url)
    url = self.driver.current_url
    while True:
        try: 
            elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[@id="pagerNext" and not(@class="disabled")]')))
            elem.click()
        except TimeoutException:
            break
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(lambda driver: self.driver.current_url != url)
        url = self.driver.current_url
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_page, dont_filter=False)
```

Note that I replaced `(By.ID, "pagerNext")` locator with `(By.XPATH, '//span[@id="pagerNext" and not(@class="disabled")]')`, so now only enabled Next button will be clicked